# Autolayout Animation Keeping UILabel Centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, autolayout

I'm writing an iOS 7 app and I have a rectangle with a label on it. The label is aligned center and is created to be the same size as the view (for simplicity when increasing the size).

The desired effect is when clicked, to animate the view to full size, with the label staying centered the whole time.

I currently have tried:

- Setting the top, left, bottom, and right constraints on the label to 0
- Setting the height and width of the label to the view at the initial size and animating it to the full size along with the view animation
- Setting the label's top and left constraints to 0 and animating the size to the full size

None of these produce the desired output. Each time the label seems to just snap to its final size before the view even starts animating.

Here is my code:

```
_viewHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;
_viewWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;
_viewTopConstraint.constant = 0;
_viewLeftConstraint.constant = 0;

_labelWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;
_labelHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;
[self.view needsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
                 animations:^(void) {
                     [self.myView layoutIfNeeded]; //perform relayout of view containing label before relayout of entire view
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
```

I'm not sure if I've provided everything necessary, as I'm still new to autolayout. However, the desired effect is a view that animates to full size while the label in the center stays centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these constraints to your label:

```
(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin   | 
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin  | 
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin    | 
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)
```

Comment: In addition to what I'm already adding? Do they need modifiers?

Comment: Just replace the label constraints in your code with `_myLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;`

Comment: This didn't work. When removing my label constraints as you suggested, the label no longer has a set height and width so it gets small and stays in the top left corner.

Comment: Try adding these on top of yours.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call needsUpdateConstraints?

All the changes occur there. Just call:

```
...
_labelWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;
_labelHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;

 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f
             animations:^(void) {
                 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
 }];
```

On a side note, why do you set height and width constraints on the label? You can just add center horizontal and vertical constraints. I don't think you can set vertical text alignment for a label. But that was not your initial issue.